# What kinds of data does the SDK collect?

Tags: here-api

If a build an app using the HERE SDK, what kinds of data (about the users, their activities, locations etc) are being sent to HERE's servers?

Comment: i don't know what that is, but have you tried checking out their documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDK collects information about the usage of SDK features.
More details: https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/legal-requirements.html

Comment: We do not collect user's location or their activities.